# check if date column contains all the hours in each year

Tags: python, pandas

I frequently need to download hourly historic data from a website in the following format

```
`            date      A     B     C
 2011/01/01 00:00    100   200   300
 2011/01/01 01:00    105   210   330
 .....
 2012/12/31 23:00    200   400   500'
```

some issue i'm having is that the online data some times misses couple hours/days per year. I need to check how many and which dates are missing to decide is the data is usable.

I normally just do `df.groupby(by = df['date'].dt.yr)['dt'].count()` and see if each year has 8760 (8784 for leap years) and check which days are missing manually. I wonder if anyone has had similar problem and knows how to write a piece of code to tell me which year is missing how many hours and which hours are missing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `asfreq` and `difference`

```
df.asfreq('H').index.difference(df.index)

DatetimeIndex(['2011-01-01 02:00:00', '2011-01-01 03:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 04:00:00', '2011-01-01 05:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 06:00:00', '2011-01-01 07:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 08:00:00', '2011-01-01 09:00:00',
               '2011-01-01 10:00:00', '2011-01-01 11:00:00',
               ...
               '2012-12-31 13:00:00', '2012-12-31 14:00:00',
               '2012-12-31 15:00:00', '2012-12-31 16:00:00',
               '2012-12-31 17:00:00', '2012-12-31 18:00:00',
               '2012-12-31 19:00:00', '2012-12-31 20:00:00',
               '2012-12-31 21:00:00', '2012-12-31 22:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=17541, freq='H')
```

Comment: thanks. I see in the doc that asfreq does not take a 'start' and 'end' argument like date_range do. does this mean asfreq take the min and max date from the df as default?

Comment: @Sinanju yes.. that is what it does.